# Chrome and Firefox incompatibility

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I have two frames, the expression running in first frame and calling highlightElements function in another frame. This expression works fine in Firefox:

```
parent.frames[0].highlightElements(lineNumbers, stringObj);
```

The highlightElements function (just for sure):

```
function highlightElements(lineNumbers, stringObj) {
  // run through the cycle and highlight them
  //for (var ln in lineNumbers) {
  var length = lineNumbers.length;
  for (var ln=0; ln<length; ln++) {
    var elements = $('.no');
    //for (var i in elements) {
    var el_length = elements.length;
    for (var i=0; i<el_length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(elements[i].innerHTML) == lineNumbers[ln]) {
        var badThing = "yes";
        for (var nextElement = elements[i].next();
             nextElement.className != '.no'; nextElement = elements[i].next()) {
          if (nextElement.innerHTML == stringObj) {
            badThing = "no";
            nextElement.effect('highlight', {}, 'slow');
            scrollIntoView(nextElement);
          }
        }
        if (badThing == "yes") alert("Didn't find the object");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in Chrome it produces the error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'highlightElement' of object[objectDOMWindow] is not a function".

How to change the expression to make it runnable in Chrome? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the function itself too?

Comment: How are you declaring the function? As a property of the frame (e.g. `window.highlightElements = function() { ... };`) or just as function (e.g. `function highlightElements() { ... }` )

Comment: to GolezTrol: I updated my answer. to Karl Nicoll: Yes, just as function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both frames are under same domain and protocol. Chome blocks javascript access from frames to another if the domains/protocols don't match. If you are working locally, and not under a local domain (i.e. the url is something like file:///C:/etc/etc.html) then it won't work either.